# How to write a string to a text file without deleting/replacing any word in the original file?

Tags: cocoa

In Cocoa, how can I write a string to a text file without replacing the contents of the file, like writing at the end of the file?

For example the following code:

```
BOOL written = [data writeToFile:[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"conf.txt"] options:NSAtomicWrite error:&error];
```

The data (string) was written to the text file however it replaced the original contents of the file.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use an [`NSFileHandle`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileHandle_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

First call [`-[NSFileHandle seekToEndOfFile]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileHandle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000304-seekToEndOfFile) to seek to the end of the file.

Then use [`-[NSFileHandle writeData:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileHandle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000304-writeData_) (instead of `-[NSData writeToFile:]`) to append your data to the end of the file.